# Retain Data Labels in Statsmodels Likehood Model

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to use the statsmodels package to do Maximum Likehood Estimation.

My goal is to compute a set of soccer team ratings given a bunch of game outcomes.

I'm using a Logistic model:

```
1/(1 + e^(HFA + HT - AT))
```

That has the following parameters:

`HFA` - home field advantage

`HT` - home team rating

`AT` - away team rating

The goal here is to compute each teams' ratings (there are 18 teams) plus a constant Home Field Advantage factor.

The data I'm given is simply a list of game outcomes - home team, away team, 1 if the home team won the game, 0 if not.

My current thinking is to enrich this data to have a column for each team. I would then make a particular column 1 if that team is playing in that particular game and 0 if not, so there should be two 1's per row. Then add another column called 'hfa', which is always 1, which represents the home field advantage.

Because of how the model works, for any given game, I need to know which team was home and which was away, then I can compute the prediction properly. And to do that, I believe I need the data labels so I can determine which of the two teams in the game was the home team. However, any time I include non-numeric data (e.g, the team name) in my `X` columns, I get an error from `statsmodels`.

Here is the gist of the code I'm trying to write. Any guidance on how to do what I'm trying to do would be much appreciated - thank you!

```
from statsmodels.base.model import GenericLikelihoodModel

class MyLogit(GenericLikelihoodModel):
    def nloglikeobs(self, params):
        """
        This function should return one evaluation of the negative log-likelihood function per observation in your
        dataset (i.e. rows of the endog/X matrix).
        """
        ???

X_cols = ['hfa'] + list(teams)
X = results[X_cols]
y = results['game_result']

model = MyLogit(X, y)
result = model.fit()

print(result.summary())
```

Comment: Why don't you use the premade models Logit or GLM with family Binomial? Using the formula interface automatically transforms categorical (e.g. string) variables. Without using formula, the user *has* to provide numeric data, that is directly used in the models..

Comment: More directly, maybe you want to preprocess your team names and convert them to a home team indicator, `1` if team was the home team, and `0` if it was not.This indicator variable can be used in exog x. (I'm not sure how you want to use the information about the team name)

Comment: Home Field Advantage is a single parameter I wanted to estimate (in addition to each team's rating). The HFA should be constant across all teams. So I need to know which team is home & which is away to compute the formula properly. My plan was: given a row of data (which contains string values for the "Home Team" and "Away Team" columns), lookup which of the two active teams is home based on the value of the 'Home Team' column, then compute the formula. I'm looking into the Logit model but i'm not sure it offers that sort of flexibility. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: what i ended up doing was just having a 1 for home team and -1 for away team and that did the trick.